# Switch rule if both elements exists in same level - SCSS

Tags: css, sass

I'm pretty sure I have done this before, but I can't find it or my Google skills are not being enough. The situation is this:

```
.card {
    // ...
    .card-title {
        margin-bottom: $spacer * .25;
    }

    .categories {
        margin-bottom: $spacer * .25;
    }
}
```

How set `margin-bottom: 0` just if any `.categories` element exists?

Comment: "*if any `.categories` element exists?*" - in the `document`, or as a sibling? Can you show HTML in which `margin-bottom` should be applied and in which it should not?

Comment: no maybe it was confusing, just when a `.categories` element exist under parent `.card` (same level)

Comment: margin-bottom:0 to cart-title?

Comment: yeah exactly! it's a simple siblings situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider [`:only-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child) with [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ca/docs/Web/CSS/:not) selector like below:

```css
.title:not(:only-child) {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">title</div>
  <div class="cat"></div>
  <div class="cat"></div>
  <div class="cat"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="title">title</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Solved using your tip on SCSS
`
&:not(.categories) .card-title {
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
`